# Cakephp validation rule for IP-Address

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to create a validation rule for Ip-Address, the code below is not working:

```
$validator
        ->add('ipfirst', 'validIp', ['rule' => 'ip', 'message' => 'Ip is not valid!'])
        ->requirePresence('ipfirst', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('ipfirst');
```

If anyone can point me in the right direct, that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already IPv4 and IPv6 validation method in Cake 3.x :-)

http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Validation.Validator.html#_ipv4 & http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Validation.Validator.html#_ipv6

Use it like so:

```
$validator
    ->ipv4('ipfirst', 'Please enter ip address')
    ->requirePresence('ipfirst', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('ipfirst');
```

Of course change to ipv6 if that's what you wanted :P

Comment: Then I'd say your issue is elsewhere, we have this working in production :-)

Comment: Can you show us the resulting request data when doing your POST/PUT?

Answer (score -2):

```
You can add custom validation rule with regular expression like:
// you can change regular expression according to you requirement.
$validator
    ->notEmpty('ipfirst', 'Please enter ip address')
    ->add('ipfirst','validIp',[
        'rule'=>  function($value){
            if (preg_match('/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/', $value)) {
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        'message'=>'Please enter a valid ip address.',
    ]);
```

Comment: No reason to make your own validation rule when it's built in! :-)